# Set timeout issue with promise (react+redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I am prototyping some mechanics for my test fun project and since I know I will be needing to delay lot of things I figured I was gonna need Promises.

However, it turns out it doesnt work how I thought it worked. And while currently this doesnt present an issue for me, I know that later on i will have to solve this.

Here is the code:

```
if(nextProps.mechanics.turn === 'enemy'){
            let enemyTurnPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                let i = 0;
                _.forEach(this.props.enemies, (enemy, index) =>{
                    setTimeout(this.handleEnemyAttack, 1000 * index)
                    i++;
                })
                resolve(i)
            })
            enemyTurnPromise.then(r =>{
                console.log('test', r);
                this.props.switchTurn('ally')

            })

        }
```

Currently I switch my state to "enemy" and it immediately switches back to "ally" and prints "i" value, while setTimeout still slowly is being resolved.

Is there any elegant way to solve this without some weird callback blocks? Can async/await help with this? Or perhaps some library that would eliminate a lot of unecessary code?

Comment: I think it's a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't specify what is the problem but trying abstract it away and want a answer to that abstract question.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is you're resolving too early. You don't want to resolve until all those timeouts have completed.

The easiest way is to start out with a promise-enabled `setTimeout`, something like this:

```
const setTimeoutPromise = delay => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
});
```

Then, sticking with promise syntax for now and assuming `this.props.enemies` is an array, you can use `map` to create a promise for each enemy, and use `Promise.all` to wait for all those to complete:

```
if(nextProps.mechanics.turn === 'enemy') {
    Promise.all(this.props.enemies.map((enemy, index) =>
        setTimeoutPromise(1000 * index).then(() => this.handleEnemyAttack(enemy))
    )).then(r => {
        console.log('test', /*...not sure what `r` is meant to be here... */);
        this.props.switchTurn('ally')
    })
}
```

Another option is to use `reduce` with a constant delay and wait for each enemy's attack to be done before the next:

```
if(nextProps.mechanics.turn === 'enemy') {
    this.props.enemies.reduce((p, enemy) =>
        p.then(() => setTimeoutPromise(1000)).then(this.handleEnemyAttack(enemy))
    , Promise.resolve())
    .then(r => {
        console.log('test', /*...not sure what `r` is meant to be here... */);
        this.props.switchTurn('ally')
    })
}
```

> Can async/await help with this?

Yes, big-time:

```
if(nextProps.mechanics.turn === 'enemy') {
    (async () => {
        for (const enemy of this.props.enemies) {
            await setTimeoutPromise(1000);
            this.handleEnemyAttack(enemy);
        }
        console.log('test', /*not sure what r is meant to be here*/);
        this.props.switchTurn('ally')
    }).catch(e => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

If the `if` above is already in an `async` function, we can remove that bit:

```
if(nextProps.mechanics.turn === 'enemy') {
    for (const enemy of this.props.enemies) {
        await setTimeoutPromise(1000);
        this.handleEnemyAttack(enemy);
    }
    console.log('test', /*not sure what r is meant to be here*/);
    this.props.switchTurn('ally')
}
```

Comment: async/await sounds great then, thank you very much, now I understand it way more than I did 1 hour ago.